# Read file with multiple spaces word by word c++

Tags: c++, ifstream

I want to read .txt file word by word and save words to strings. The problem is that the .txt file contains multiple spaces between each word, so I need to ignore spaces.

Here is the example of my .txt file:

```
John      Snow  15
Marco  Polo     44
Arya    Stark   19
```

As you see, each line is another person, so I need to check each line individualy.

I guess the code must look something like this:

```
ifstream file("input.txt");
string   line;

while(getline(file, line))
{
    stringstream linestream(line);
    string name;
    string surname;
    string years;

    getline(linestream, name, '/* until first not-space character */');
    getline(linestream, surname, '/* until first not-space character */');
    getline(linestream, years, '/* until first not-space character */');

   cout<<name<<" "<<surname<<" "<<years<<endl;
}
```

Expected result must be:

```
John Snow 15
Marco Polo 44
Arya Stark 19
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read file line by line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/read-file-line-by-line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `operator>>` of `istream`, it takes care of multiple whitespace for you:

```
ifstream file("input.txt");
string   line;

while(!file.eof())
{
    string name;
    string surname;
    string years;

    file >> name >> surname >> years;

    cout<<name<<" "<<surname<<" "<<years<<endl;
}
```